# Better solution to using Url.Action in javascript code

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my current project using asp.net MVC 3 (using razor), when I'm making Ajax calls, I have to keep the JS on the view page because I want to use Url.Action to generate the URL. This means I can't split the js code out into .JS files, Is there a better solution than what I'm currently doing.

Comment: Simon, I recently answered this question but actually found the accepted answer to be a much neater solution. take a look here for a nice simple solution to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624626/do-you-write-your-javascript-in-a-asp-net-mvc-view-or-in-a-separate-javascrip/4625478#4625478 cheers..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I tend to accomplish this in a similar way as above, with a slightly different twist as I like namespacing my javascript.

The javascript file looks something like:

```
var my = {};

my.viewname = 
{
   init : function(settings){
      // do some work here. settings.someImportantUrl has my json/ajax url eg.
      alert(settings.someImportantUrl );
   }
}
```

Then my view would contain something like:

```
<script language='javascript'>
  // allocate an object with variables you want to use in the external js file
  var settings = {someImportantUrl: '<%=Url.Action(...)%>'};
  // call an init method for the current view
  my.viewname.init(settings);
</script>
```

Comment: So jamiec, to pull the URL's out of the JS again I just use JS object notation like var url = my.namespace.settings.UserEditUrl, is this correct?

Comment: @Simon - within the `init` method, you can use settings.whatever to access variables you have allocated within the view to the settings object. re-read example, it should be clear.

Comment: jamie, just to add, you would of course add `var my = {};` to your initial javascript file section :-)

Comment: think I'll go with your suggestion Jamie, one off topic question though, why namespace your JS, what does this bring to the table, Cheers

Comment: @Simon - The same thing namespaces bring to any programming; organisation, clarity & good practice.

Answer (score 9):

You can define only urls in view and keep all other javascript code in .js files.

There is code from view in my MVC.NET 1 application:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/Account/ManageUsers.js")%>"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/Account/ManageUsersAndGroups.js")%>"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var getUsersUrl = '<%= Url.Action("GetUsers", "Account") %>';
    var getUserDetailsURL = '<%= Url.Action("GetUserDetails", "Account") %>';

    <%If Not ViewData("readOnly") Then%>
    var changeRolePermissionsUrl = '<%= Url.Action("ChangeRolePermissions", "Account") %>';
    var deleteUserUrl = '<%= Url.Action("DeleteUser", "Account") %>';
    var resetPasswordUrl = '<%= Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account") %>';
    var updateUserGroupsUrl = '<%= Url.Action("UpdateUserGroups", "Account") %>';
    var updateUserDetailsUrl = '<%= Url.Action("UpdateUserDetails", "Account") %>';
    <%End If%>  
</script>
```

So, you can even don't render urls for actions which cannot be invoked by user because of security reasons. (`ViewData("readOnly")` means user have read only access to screen).

And there is a part of code in js file:

```
function GetUsersList() {
    ajax.getJSON(getUsersUrl, {}, function(data) {
        if (data != false) {
            ShowUsers(data);
        }
        else {
            jAlert('Error during users list retrieving.');
        }
    });
}
```

Where `getUsersUrl` is defined in View

Comment: I was thinking along these lines, i.e. Keeping a collection of all my Ajax urls in a shared ascx and maintaining that, I just want to make sure I'm not missing something else that may have been easier

Comment: I'm not seeing a better way. But I could say that my practise is good. It is used in a big project for about 1.5 year and we don't have any problems in development and maintenance.

Comment: This is the best solution i get. Thanks @Egor4eg

Answer (score 1):

your javascript code should be reside in separate javascript file. you can use global variables to link your view and javascript. E.g. view page looks like below.

```
view html ...
<script type="text/javascript">
var pageUrl = @GetURL()
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script.js"/>
```

`script.js` file use the `pageUrl` variable and other global variables.

Comment: but I'll still need to hard code the URL path inside the JS file, and I don't want to do this I want MVC to create the Url's for me.

Comment: @Simon no you don't need to hardcode path inside js due to global variables defined in your view, generated by MVC

Comment: ah ok, Adeel, your suggestion is similar to Egor4eg answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of security ramifications on this, but another way to do it would be to use the @Url.Action to set the 'id' of the html markup, then you can create a javascript click function, like the following:

**View**

```
<div class="someClickable" id='@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")'>
</div>
```

**Referenced javascript file**

```
$(function() {
    $('someClickable').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.id,
            success: someJSFunction,
            dataType: "html"
        });
    });
});
```

You end up with the desired url stored in the 'id' of the 'div'.  This seems to be a reasonable solution as long as you are doing read only actions.