# How to get @Url.Action url in a separate script file?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a file for my javascript separate from my web pages.
However what this appears to mean is that I cannot write the following line;

```
var url = '@Url.Action("AddTrade", "DataService")';
```

I am reluctant to hard code the url in case it is different when I deploy it.

So what should I do about this?

Comment: Related to / Duplicated by: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781552/better-soluton-to-using-url-action-in-javascript-code

Comment: That link has the best answer

Answer (score 1):

I use an object to print all the urls I'll use from the scripts. This code goes into the _Layout or any view.

Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    windows.Urls = {};
    window.Urls["SomeKey"] = "@Url.Action("AddTrade", "DataService")";
</script>
```

Then, from the scripts, you use:

```
var url = window.Urls["SomeKey"];
// Or even easier:
var url = Urls.SomeKey
```

Comment: +1. But I cant understand fully, Could you give usage example? Where do you define, and where do you use? Thanks a lot

Comment: after edit: And, call above code in external js file like this `var url = window.Urls["SomeKey"];`  ? right ?

Comment: As an alternate approach, you might want to look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14281042/195550